# After updated my Xcode 13.3.1, I unable to run my flutter project with the error CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state

Tags: android, ios, swift, xcode, flutter

Error in console:

Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).

Version Details:
dart: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"
flutter: ">=2.10.0"
Xcode Version: 13.3.1
Android Studio Version: 4.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Install Cocoapods
Install CocoaPods if You are using brew then run the following command.

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Or

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

And then find the path where CocoaPods is installed on your machine with the following command.

```
which pod
```

Then set your project path in the terminal. So in your ~/.profile add the following lines:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/{username}/.gem/ruby-{xyz}/bin"
```

Now, apply changes and try to run again

Solution 2: Run This Command
Try to start Android studio from the terminal:

```
open /Applications/Android\ myApplication.app
```

Hope your issue may be resolved.

Comment: HI @Yogita, thanks. but i just found if i add any firebase related library then i got the error i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved that by changing my Android Studio version Dophin(2021.3.1) Canary 9.

I tried Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1. But it wasn't launching in my macOS. So I tried that version.

Just try to update your Android Studio to the latest.